# Why does my react render does not show up on soft refresh (with cache) only when I hard refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

UPDATE: Apparently it shows up when I press 'Ctrl + Shift + R' but no idea why...

I had it working just fine where my icon was showing up where I wanted but for some reason it stopped working and when I go to Console it shows that the problem is in my .tsx file, saying that my querySelector is null (I can see it isn't when I run the code on console

I tried removing all the "extra" lines and left it very simple and still won't work

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class IconComp extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="IconIDIconID">I</div>

        )
    }
}

const app: HTMLElement = document.createElement('div') as HTMLElement;
const pos: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('.gb_1d.gb_3a.gb_Pd.gb_4d') as HTMLElement;
pos.appendChild(app);
ReactDOM.render(<IconComp />, app);
```

Comment: "it shows up when I press 'Ctrl + Shift + R'" - Do you know what Ctrl-Shift-R does in the Chrome browser? If not: [Chrome keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179) > Webpage shortcuts

Comment: Yeah I noticed that as well, shouldn't it just show up when the page is refreshed? I'm new to JavaScript so I don't really know why this JS is so annoying sometimes